# LocalStorage начальный значения

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Использую local storage для сохранения игры, cобираюсь сохранить массив, но ему нужны начальные значения неравные нулю, как осуществить?

Comment: `ему нужны` - кому ему? `как осуществить?` -  осуществить что?

Comment: МНЕ нужно чтобы там были значения

Comment: `там` - это где?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, в массиве, очевидно

Comment: @Grundy с чего ты взял?) там же можно и ноль содержать, а значит не понятно где)

Comment: Я хочу чтобы в массиве были начальные значения(не ноль) потом они будут меняться и сохраняться снова в массив, задача в том чтобы при перезагрузке страницы значения не переписались на начальные

Comment: ну так запиши в него значения не ноль.  что тебе мешает это сделать?

Comment: То что при перезагрузке страницы значения которые сохранились перезаписываются на те что вношу я, а мне этого не нужно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо ты хочешь что-то подобное:

```js
// Начальный массив
var initArray = [555,666,777];
// Загрузка игровых данных, где возвращается либо массив из localStorage
// либо если его не существует еще, то загружается initArray 
var gameData = loadGameData(initArray);

document.write(gameData[0] + "<br/>");
document.write(gameData[1] + "<br/>");
document.write(gameData[2] + "<br/>");

function loadGameData(initArray) { 
    return getGameData() || initArray; 
}

// Возвращает данные из localStorage, если он существует
function getGameData() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('gameData'))
        return localStorage.getItem('gameData').split(',');
  
   return false;      
}

// Какой-то игровой процесс
// ...
// ...
// ...
// Сохранение данных
gameData = [1,2,3];
localStorage.setItem('gameData', gameData);
```

Вообще массив - не самая удобная вещь для хранения в `localStorage`. Обычно там хранят скорее `Json`, что и советовал бы.